# Getting a bug while Updating a Loop - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So while doing this loop in order do to organize the words with most number of characters, I tried to cycle my list and after finding the word with the most number of characters of them all, removing it from the list and runing again and so on.
The problem besides that I keep getting the error: `list.remove(x): x not in list` which I assigned being related to the back that I keep updating my string. From my research I found that I needed to create and auxiliar string but I cant figure it out...

```
frase=str(input('Introduza uma frase: '))
primeira=frase.split()
print(len(primeira))
segunda=[]
print(len(segunda))
maxx=''


while len(primeira)!=0:
    for i in (primeira and aux):
        if len(i)>len(maxx):
            maxx=i
        print(maxx)
    segunda.append(maxx)
    aux.remove(maxx)


print(primeira)
print(segunda[::-1])
```

Comment: What is `aux` that you are using?Is it empty?

Comment: you probably need to update `maxx` to `''` again at the beginning of each iteration of your while loop

Comment: Tacratis, that was what I done! Thanks for the advice since it worked well. Thank you also for all the answers!

Answer (score 3):

`while len(primeira)!=0:` is creating an infinite loop, because you are never altering *primeira* so its length never changes.

The pythonic way to loop through a list is:

```
for element in the_list:
   <do stuff>
```

Comment: Yes but my objective was when I reached absolute 0 numbers in my list, It would stop. Even with defining a counter.... But I already sorted it out! Thanks anyway.